# Posting facebook status

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit, phantomjs

I'm trying to figure out how to use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). I wrote the script below to try and automate posting a Facebook status. As far as I'm aware, the script isn't even logging in, which I'm unsure why. My code is below:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('https://www.facebook.com/', function() {
    page.includeJs("//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js", function() {
        page.evaluate(function() {

           // Login
           $('#email').val('email_here'); // Set email
           $('#pass').val('password_here'); // Set PW
           $('#u_0_4').click();

           // Set status        
           $('#u_0_1p').val('123');
           $('#u_0_1f').submit();

         });
       phantom.exit()
    });
});
```

I'm not sure why the script won't work, or even to get some sort of error message output so I can figure out why my script isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code for Loging in facebook i have written this in javascript it login's and takes a screen shot of your facebook home page..

```
 var page = require('webpage').create();

     var fillLoginInfo = function(){    
             var frm = document.getElementById("login_form");
             frm.elements["email"].value = 'your fb email/username'; 
             frm.elements["pass"].value = 'password';  
             frm.submit();
     }
     page.onLoadFinished = function(){
      if(page.title == "Welcome to Facebook - Log In, Sign Up or Learn More"){
           page.evaluate(fillLoginInfo);    
           return;
       }
            else        
                 page.render('./screens/some.png'); 
            console.log("completed");   
            phantom.exit();
     } 

     page.open('https://www.facebook.com/');
```

Find this on Github: https://github.com/manishjo/Automation/blob/master/facebook_automation/fbScreenshot.js

Still trying to find out after login how to Post msg.

Thanks,
Manish Joshi